# Common Lisp how trace works during going downward

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I dont know how to explain it on topic, hence sorry about title.

```
(defun uniq (lst &optional ulst)
(if (endp lst)
    ulst
    (if (member (car lst) ulst)
        (uniq (cdr lst) ulst)
        (uniq (cdr lst) (append ulst (list (car lst))))
    )  
))
```

Procedure UNIQ takes a list and removes all the repeated elements in the list keeping only the first occurrence.

When i trace it, i ve got result this:

```
(UNIQ) * (uniq '(1 2 3 5 1 2 3 8 3))
  0: (UNIQ (1 2 3 5 1 2 3 8 3))
    1: (UNIQ (2 3 5 1 2 3 8 3) (1))
      2: (UNIQ (3 5 1 2 3 8 3) (1 2))
        3: (UNIQ (5 1 2 3 8 3) (1 2 3))
          4: (UNIQ (1 2 3 8 3) (1 2 3 5))
            5: (UNIQ (2 3 8 3) (1 2 3 5))
              6: (UNIQ (3 8 3) (1 2 3 5))
                7: (UNIQ (8 3) (1 2 3 5))
                  8: (UNIQ (3) (1 2 3 5 8))
                    9: (UNIQ NIL (1 2 3 5 8))
                    9: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
                  8: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
                7: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
              6: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
            5: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
          4: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
        3: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
      2: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
    1: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
  0: UNIQ returned (1 2 3 5 8)
(1 2 3 5 8)
```

I understand that trace shows me the recurison process, which i can see the results when going from 0 to 9.
However what i dont understand is what is going on when it is going downwards back which is from 9 to 0 again. 
When i went from 0 to 9 i thougt program already gave me result, am i right? 
Hence what is the purpose of going downwards than?

Answer (score 3):

> *Hence what is the purpose of going downwards than?*

The purpose of going downwards is that all the recursive calls have to return.

This looks like it has no purpose because they are returning the same value.

A wise person once asked the same question as you, and invented tail call optimization, which eliminates all those returns.

Write a recursive factorial function (in the most obvious way) and trace that; you will see that the returns are doing something then: the actual compounded multiplications to calculate the factorial.

Comment: yes, factorial gave me the incremental results. now i realized that when we are going upwards it does not give solution it states recursion. results are given with the going downwards section. if i got it right :)

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Kaz's answer: if you try this in an implementation which has a moderately good compiler you may well find this:

```
> (trace uniq)
(uniq)

> (uniq '(1 2 3 5 1 2 3 8 3))
0 uniq > ...
  >> lst : (1 2 3 5 1 2 3 8 3)
0 uniq < ...
  << VALUE-0 : (1 2 3 5 8)
(1 2 3 5 8)
```

Not only are there no annoying returns-of-the-same-thing, there are no recursive calls at all: they've all been optimised away to jumps.

But if you intentionally prohibit the compiler from doing anything clever, by adding a `notinline` declaration for `uniq` within its body, then you'll see all the useless calls & returns.

Comment: thank you, but i can not use sophisticated compiler since every code piece should be in my control.

Comment: @inspiron: I'm not aware of any extant CL implementations without sophisticated compilers.

Comment: im using just SBCL on ubuntu terminal :)

Comment: @inspiron: SBCL has arguably the most advanced CL compiler in existence, I think.